# how to match python list item with regular expression

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
def popular_words(text, words):
    """(str, array) -> dictionary
    returns dictionary  search words are the keys and values
    are the number of times when those words are occurring
    in a given text
    """
    word_dictionary = {}

    for word in words:     
        list = re.findall(word, text, re.IGNORECASE)
        word_dictionary.update({word : len(list) })

    return word_dictionary

popular_words('''
When I was One
I had just begun
When I was Two
I was nearly new
''', ['i', 'was', 'three', 'near'])
```

How do I ignore 'near' in the text string and not match to 'nearly'
I've tried using \bword\b to define the word boundary and the error was:

> "unexpected character after line continuation character"

Answer (score 0):

You can match the whole word by defining word boundary like this,

```
\b[a-zA-Z]+\b
```

Python code:

```
regex = r"\b[a-zA-Z]+\b"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use string formatting and \b. That error you got may have been because you didn't use a raw string like this (always use raw strings with re if you're using backslashes, it makes life easier.):

```
import re
def popular_words(text, words):
    """(str, array) -> dictionary
    returns dictionary  search words are the keys and values
    are the number of times when those words are occurring
    in a given text
    """
    word_dictionary = {}

    for word in words:

            list = re.findall(r'\b{0}\b'.format(word), text, re.IGNORECASE)
            word_dictionary.update({word : len(list) })

    return word_dictionary

print(popular_words('''
When I was One
I had just begun
When I was Two
I was nearly new
''', ['i', 'was', 'three', 'near']))
```

output:

```
{'i': 4, 'near': 0, 'was': 3, 'three': 0}
```

EDIT: for the sake of completeness. This is what you'd have to use to not use a raw string. You have to escape backslashes by doubling them.

```
list = re.findall('\\b{0}\\b'.format(word), text, re.IGNORECASE)
```